# Bind DataContext and not set in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datacontext

I have a `WPF` application and I use `Prism` and `Unity`. I have also two custom user controls:

1. `PlotViewControl`
2. `PlotViewReport`

The second uses the first control in a `DataTemplate`.

If I want to call:

```
regionManager.RequestNavigate("RightRegion", "PlotViewControl", parameters);
```

The DataContext for `PlotViewControl` must be set in `PlotViewControl.xamls.cs` like so:

```
this.DataContext =  new PlotViewModel();
```

If I want to use the above `UserControl` in `PlotViewReport` in the following manner, I must remove the line above.

```
<ListView Name="PlotLista" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedValue}" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding PlotReportModelList}" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!--<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding }">-->
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                <pv:PlotViewControl DataContext="{Binding }"  />
            </StackPanel>
            <!--</ItemsControl>-->
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

So, which is the solution to be able to use the both scenarios.

Comment: I suppose you have that PlotLista ListView in a window. Which one is the DataContext for that? Where is  PlotReportModelList located?

Comment: In  the ViewModel class of PlotViewReport .

Answer (score 0):

Taking into consideration that you set the DataContext as {Binding} inside the ItemTemplate, this will point to the current ListView item. So, you have to use a RelativeSource binding to get to the DataContext of the ListView.

```
Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}, Path=DataContext.ViewModel}"
```